# How to delete/update datagridview checkbox from datagridview C#

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview

Im trying to delete 2 checkbox columns from datagridview because Im trying to update data, so basically I need a way to delete those columns (Im dropping all columns besides those 2 and putting a new datatable with updated data from database) or to Update columns when a button "save" is pressed.

To better explane the problem, here are some screenshots:

Before pressing "save":

[image]

After pressing "save":
[image]

My idea of updating datagridview:

```
        NpgsqlDataAdapter da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(command_odjel_id);
        dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        Radni_sati_tablica.DataSource = dt;
```

After that I add those 2 checkbox columns ( there is a query for filling those checkboxes but thats irelevant for this question):

```
        DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn bolovanje = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
        bolovanje.HeaderText = "Bolovanje";
        bolovanje.Width = 30;
        Radni_sati_tablica.Columns.Insert(0, bolovanje);

        DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn godisnji = new  DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn(); 
        godisnji.HeaderText = "Godisnji";
        godisnji.Width = 30;
        Radni_sati_tablica.Columns.Insert(1, godisnji);
```

After that I do Update with the query and I finish with:

```
                Radni_sati_tablica.DataSource=null;
                Radni_sati_tablica.DataSource = dt;
                Radni_sati_tablica.Update();
```

Basically all I need is to update table with new data that has been inputed, I just need a way to do it.

Comment: Show the updating code? Check that `DatagridView.AutoGenerateColumns = false`. But without the code - how you load data, update data it is difficult to answer

Comment: Share some of your code, for example updating code

Comment: @Fabio  there you go =)

Comment: Do not add new columns to the `DataGridView` - instead create and add columns to the `DataTable` - then when you set new `DataTable` to the `DataGridView.DataSource` manually added columns will be gone.

Answer (score 1):

Good day! In order to delete and update in SQL, you must use the commands: UPDATE and DELETE.